# Copy list of files with same name but different extensions

Tags: batch-file

I'm working with hundreds of `ESRI` shapefiles and `LiDAR` files.  Each file has the same name but a different extension.  Basically, a primary file and several secondary files. I have a list of filenames (minus the extensions) I need to copy from one location (`C:\Source`) to another, empty directory (`C:\Destination`).

For example, I have a textfile with a list of files I want to copy: `A`, `C`, e.t.c. (name of the file only, not including extensions nor a directory path).

The source directory includes files:

```
A.shp
A.shx
A.dbf
B.shp
B.shx
B.dbf
C.shp
C.shx
C.dbf
C.prj
```

I only want to copy all files for `A` and `C` to a destination directory (but not files name `B`). Also, shapefiles must have at least these three files, but may or may not have several more secondary files (`.prj`, `.sbn`, `.shp` `.xml`, `.cpg`, and more).

[image: Example source directory, text file, and destination directory, with script.]

Comment: `for /f %a in (list.txt) do copy %a.* destination\ `, when I understood you correctly

Comment: Adding to Stephan's answer, if you put this code in a batch file you will need to duplicate `%` before for-loop variables so `%a` becomes `%%a`. Please include a more clear example: an input text file (we need to understand how it is formatted), a directory listing, and a list of files which should and should not be copied (it is not very clear if you want to copy files with all extensions or only the three of them you listed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```bat
@echo off

cd /d full_path\you\have\your_list
for /f "delims=" %%A IN (your_list.txt) do copy "C:\Source\%%A.*" "C:\destination\"
```

The above solution was for a batch file. For cmd you can simply:

```bat
cd /d full_path\you\have\your_list
for /f "delims=" %A IN (your_list.txt) do copy "C:\Source\%A.*" "C:\destination\"
```

`delims=` option used not to split the lines of the file. For this reason, I quoted source and destination path!

Comment: `for /f "usebackq delims=" %%A in ("D:\temp0\testcopylist.txt") do copy "D:\temp1\%%A.*" "D:\temp2\"`. Be sure, there are no stray spaces in your listfile.